# How to parse a Java string into 2 double numbers and eliminate an invalid input?

Tags: java, string, parsing, string-matching

I am trying to parse a string which should contain a `Complex Number` into a `ComplexNumber` class that I wrote.

the string should be in the following format:
`realNumber+imageNumberi`, e.g : `14-3i`.

I want to be able to:

1. recognize if the string that was received is valid or not. If it has any characters in it which are not `+`, `-`, `.` or `i` or a `digit`, I want to be able to throw an exception error. e.g if the received string is `13a + 3i`.
2. Remove spaces (I did it using `str.replaceAll`), e.g : `13          +      i`
3. when I finally have the "fixed" string that looks like `12-3i` for example, I want to  be able to split it into 2 double values of `12` and `3`.
4. I want to be able to also change `i` to `1` or '-1' if needed, e.g: `-15+i`.

I read about `regex` so I tried to use `String.match`, but had no luck with it.
I also succeeded to make a 50% working solution.

This is one way that I tried to do that.
run over the string, remove space, and go through each character to check if its valid or not. I had no luck because it writes: `Condition '!Character.isDigit(ch) || ch != '+' || ch != '-'' is always 'true'` .

```
String parsed = str.replaceAll("\\s++", "");

        for(int i = 0; i < parsed.length(); i++) {
            char ch = parsed.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch) || ch != '+' || ch != '-')
            {
                System.out.println("invalid string.");

            }
```

I also wrote tried

```
if (!Character.isDigit(ch) || "+-".contains(ch))
```

and

```
if("~#@*+%{}<>[]|\"_^".contains(ch)){
```

but received:
`Required type: CharSequence Provided: char`

the following solution works but lacks of:

- check if the string is valid.
- change `i` with `1` if `i` received without a value before.
- determine if its `+` or `-` the image number.

**code**:

```
String[] splitString = str.split("[+|s+|i]"); // removing spaces, plus sign and "i" from the string

        Double[] complexNumberFields = new Double[2];
        complexNumberFields[0] = Double.parseDouble(splitString[0]);
            complexNumberFields[1] = Double.parseDouble(splitString[1]);
        }
        return new ComplexNumber(complexNumberFields[0], complexNumberFields[1]);
```

How should I implement this function in the best way without using a `parser` or `matcher` (becaue I did not read about them yet). I want it to be done with regex and string manipulations.

And without using any `ComplexFormat` methods of course because i'm implementing my own `ComplexNumber` class.

Comment: I shall have to be the first here to say that regex is not really (despite appearances) a suitable tool for building an expression parser

Comment: @g00se I meant that the regex will be used in order to determine if the string is valid or not and if it contains not valid characters.

Comment: @g00se  =)  It depends on how you gonna use it =) (Check my answer)

Comment: Right off the bat, you assume the expression starts with two digits. Why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to implement this method inside Class (like Integer.valueOf() ex  ComplexNumber.valueOf(“14-3i”))

Value of implementation:
I would do this with regExp in case you don’t have any reason to avoid it (ex. performance) And also you can make my regExp more complex and flexible to cover more cases. I use Lombok here to decrease class construction noise (you can create constructors and get/set)

Also, please note that I set imageNumber as a string in case you need to parse only double just change parsing method or regular expression (regex variable) to   "^(\d{2})\-(\d)[a-zA-Z]{1}$";

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ComplexNumber {

    private double realNumber;
    private String imageNumber;


    public static ComplexNumber valueOf(String inputValue) throws Exception {

        final String regex = "^(\\d{2})\\-(\\d[a-zA-Z]{1})$";


        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputValue);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // constrict the object
            ComplexNumber obj = new ComplexNumber();
            obj.setRealNumber(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1)));
            obj.setImageNumber(matcher.group(2));
            return obj;
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }

}
```